# After copying files from mac to pc and back to mac, my .xcodeproj file is showing up as a folder

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, filesystems

How can I get this back to a "file" I can open with xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may well be a better way, but you can convince OSX to make the change by first renaming it to something without an extension (myProject.xcodeproj becomes myProject), then renaming again, adding the extension back in (myProject becomes myProject.xcodeproj).

I just tried it and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Thanks, was worried there! :)

Answer (score 0):

Because HFS filesystems hold a lot more metadata than most others, including FAT and NTFS, copying entire branches, e.g. folders of files, onto other filesystems tends to lose stuff like the bundle state.
Different copy methods also have different copy results, depending on whether the invisible files are picked up by the copy.
The best way to address this is by either compressing the whole branch before moving it off HFS, or by keeping the branch on a virtual disk that you mount from your mac as needed.